# how to open Table inside a table in HTML CSS and asp.net mvc

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables in SQL database customers and orders. a customer has multiple orders what I want if I click on a TR, a new table will be coming between that TR and the next TR. What happens is that the TR that comes after the TR(which contains the inside table), is not part of the table structure, which it's supposed to be. here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer_list](
[customer_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[ContactName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[phone] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[address] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[city] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[postalcode] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order_list](
[OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
[customer_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[OrderDate] [date] NULL,
[ShipDate] [date] NULL,
[address] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[ShipName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[postalcode] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication7.Models
{
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

}
public class Orders
{
    public int  OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string ShipName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
public class MasterDetails
{
    public List<Customer> CustPersonal { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> CustRegions { get; set; }

}
}
```

Repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Dapper;
using WebApplication7.Models;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication7.Repository
{
        public class CustomerRepo
        {
            //To Handle connection related activities   
            SqlConnection con;
            private void connection()
            {
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString();
                con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            }
            /// <summary>  
            /// Get Multiple Table details  
            /// </summary>  
            /// <returns></returns>  
            public IEnumerable<MasterDetails> GetMasterDetails()
            {
                connection();
                con.Open();
                var objDetails = SqlMapper.QueryMultiple(con, "GetMasterDetails", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                MasterDetails ObjMaster = new MasterDetails();

                //Assigning each Multiple tables data to specific single model class  
                ObjMaster.CustPersonal = objDetails.Read<Customer>().ToList();
                ObjMaster.CustRegions = objDetails.Read<Orders>().ToList();

                List<MasterDetails> CustomerObj = new List<MasterDetails>();
                //Add list of records into MasterDetails list  
                CustomerObj.Add(ObjMaster);
                con.Close();

                return CustomerObj;

            }
        }
  
}
```

controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication7.Models;
using WebApplication7.Repository;

namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult MasterDetail()
        {
            CustomerRepo objDet = new CustomerRepo();
            MasterDetails CustData = new MasterDetails();

            List<MasterDetails> MasterData = objDet.GetMasterDetails().ToList();

            CustData.CustPersonal = MasterData[0].CustPersonal;
            CustData.CustRegions = MasterData[0].CustRegions;


            return View(CustData);
        }
    }
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication7.Models.MasterDetails>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MasterDetail";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5 class="btn btn-primary">Customer Type Master</h5>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-hover col-md-3">

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Contact Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Phone
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Address
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            City
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Postal Code
                        </th>
                    </tr>


                    @{
                        //To make unique Id
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var item in Model.CustPersonal)
                        {

                            <tr>
                                <td>


                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustPersonal[i].name, new { @id = "Name_" + i })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustPersonal[i].phone, new { @id = "NCustomerType_" + i })


                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustPersonal[i].address, new { @id = "Gender_" + i })
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustPersonal[i].city, new { @id = "Gender_" + i })
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5 class="btn btn-primary">Customer Orders</h5>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover col-md-3">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Order ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Order Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Ship Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Ship Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            address
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Postal Code
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    @{
                        //To make unique Id
                        int j = 0;
                        foreach (var item in Model.CustRegions)
                        {

                            <tr>
                                <td>


                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].OrderID, new { @id = "OrderID_" + j })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].OrderDate, new { @id = "OrderDate_" + j })


                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].ShipDate, new { @id = "ShipDate_" + j })
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].ShipName, new { @id = "ShipName_" + j })
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].address, new { @id = "address_" + j })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.CustRegions[j].PostalCode, new { @id = "PostalCode_" + j })
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
                        }
```

here is an image I expect the output
[image]

Comment: So where is your code ?

Comment: @NegiRox i have added all code

Comment: you can not directly do that you need to use some client side scripting